# Issue as soon as click on pom.xml or updating maven dependencies in spring starter project

Tags: maven, java-8, spring-tool-suite, sts

I have installed sts4 and Java 1.8. I have created a spring starter project. project created but as soon as click on pom.xml I'm getting below error. I have also configured Apache Maven in STS.

Can somebody help me?

[image]

Comment: [STS-4-Known-Limitations-&-Issues](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Known-Limitations-&-Issues):
> - **Java 11+ required** ...

Comment: You need a JDK 11+ to run the IDE, but STS4 comes with an embedded JDK17 that is used to run the IDE by default, so that should be a problem here (just guessing). And you should be able to use a JDK 1.8 for your projects (independent of the JDK that is used to run the IDE). I would recommend to raise an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues and add details, especially the exact stack trace of the exception from the Error Log view and a few steps how to reproduce this.